# Send SMS - Sent broadcast

Tags: java, android

I'm sending an SMS and registering a receiver for the sent event:

```
public void sendSMS(Context context){
    PendingIntent sentPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent("MY_SENT_INTENT"), 0);

    BroadcastReceiver smsSent = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1){
            System.out.printl("Do something!");
        }
    }

    context.registerReceiver(smsSent, new IntentFilter("MY_SENT_INTENT"));

    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage("XXXXXXXXXXX", null, "message", sentPendingIntent, null); 
}
```

Is there a way to send the broadcast event directly to my application?

Comment: call your method inside onReceive method

Comment: I think he wants a blocking call.

Comment: Actualy, I need that the broadcast would be sent directly to my application.

Comment: You are already in your application? But do you want to execute it on the same thread?

Comment: I suppose that the SMS application is broadcasting the PendingIntent to all apps, but I would like to know if there is a way to send it directly to my app. I don't know if it's possible...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by:

- Creating my custom BroadcastReceiver class:

  ```
  public class SmsSentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{ /*...*/ }
  ```
- Declaring the receiver in the manifest file:

  ```
  <application>
      <!-- ... -->
      <receiver name="package.SmsSentReceiver">
      </receiver>
  </application>
  ```
- Creating the explicity intent:

  ```
  public void sendSMS(Context context){
      Intent sentIntent = new Intent(context, SmsSentReceiver.class);
      PendingIntent sentPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, sentIntent, 0);
      SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
      smsManager.sendTextMessage("XXXXXXXXXXX", null, "message", sentPendingIntent, null); 
  }
  ```